# Rails: Make all users change their passwords within Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

Is there a way to ask all users to change their passwords upon 
logging into a Rails application using Devise authentication? In other words, I'd like a way to "expire" a password, so that the next time a user signs in, they have to change it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Devise can do that out of the box, but i guess it's pretty to do it yourself. What i would do :

1. Upon user sign in, i would nil out the encrypted_password field of the database.
2. I would have overriden devise's session controller (responsible for the logins), in order to check whether encrypted_password of a user that tries to log in is nil.
3. If that was nil, i would redirect them to login, also flashing an error like "Your password has expired. Please create a new one."

Comment: Don't forgot to somehow remember the encrypted_password before nil'ing it, or you'll be sorry.